# How to reduce the app size containing .so files of size more than 100 MB

Tags: android, performance, .so

My app size has reached to 100 MB, so i used the `analyze apk` tool to found out the cause, and the culprit were not `res` or `aar` but `.so` files. around 49% of the total app size is used by these `.so` files.

[image]

[image]

I have not added any of these in libs folder, but the other `aar` files that i have added in my project are adding these `.so` files.

This is what i added in `gradle`

```
 defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
 }
```

If i remove `x86` from the the gradle, the size of apk reduced drastically, but i am not sure if this will break anything.

I have following questions;

1. Is it necessary to add `.so` for both `armeabi` & `x86`
2. Does Proguard effects `.so` files ?
3. Is there any way to remove unused `.so` files
4. What is the use of `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` files.

Comment: You can upload different APKs for the different ABIs to Playstore. An x86 will get the x86 version, an ARM will get the ARm version. https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#MultiApks

Comment: @Christopher: Thanks, I understand the concept, I will create 2 APK's one with abiFilters armeabi-x86 and one with {abiFilters x86}, I will look for the documentation of uploading and managing multiple apk;s

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check this story out? https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e